# Cmake : Dependency to run if there's any change

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cmake-gui

I'm new to Cmake and I have a main output named `TARGET`. I'm trying to add custom target named `_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET` as a dependency to main `TARGET`. I want `TARGET` to rebuild `_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET` automatically if there's any change in `_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET`. `_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET` should depend on change in folders.

Here's the code I tried to implement:

```
 if (NOT TARGET ${_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET})
            add_custom_target(${_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET})
            add_dependencies(${_ARGS_PROJECT_TARGET} ${_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET})
            set_property(TARGET ${_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET} PROPERTY FOLDER "Targets")
        endif()

        add_custom_command(TARGET ${_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET}
            ${_COMMANDS}
            VERBATIM
        )
```

I'm trying visual studio to debug and if I rebuild `_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET` then only I can see the updated output. I would like to know how I can link my folders to `_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET` so that `TARGET` automatically builds new code

Comment: Please provide an MRE.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} ${_COMMANDS}
            DEPENDS ${DEPENDENT_DIRECTORY}
            VERBATIM
        )

        add_custom_target(${_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET} ALL 
            DEPENDS ${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
        )

        add_dependencies(${_ARGS_PROJECT_TARGET} ${_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET})
        set_property(TARGET ${_COPY_ASSETS_TARGET} PROPERTY FOLDER "Targets")
```

I found this to be working for my project